# Can I avoid entering double negative signs in an HTML numeric input

Tags: html, input

My goal is to ensure that a classic `<input type="number">` can only show a single minus sign at the beginning of the number (like... normal negative numbers?).

It feels quite dumb to ask this, but currently, in the following input I am able to input "--1", "-1-" or "1--", and in those cases, the value property of the native element just gives me an empty string. Is this somehow intended?

Comment: The 2nd dash is to allow exponential notation (ex: `-1.2e-3`) You can add a pattern to disallow it. Ex, for integers: `<input type="number" pattern="-?[0-9]+">`

Comment: @001 This sounded promising but unfortunately the regex pattern seems to only be used when the form is validated, e.g. as part of a submit: https://jsfiddle.net/z6osdcra/1/ . In my case I'd need the input field to prevent the double minus in the first place (since field values are being auto saved on blur).

Answer (score 4):

try this :D!

```
       <input
        type="number"
        onKeyPress={event => {
          if (event?.key === "e" || event?.key === "+") {
            event.preventDefault();
          }
          if (event.target.value.length == 0 && event?.key === "-") {
            event.target.value = "";
          }
          if (event.target.value.length > 0 && event?.key === "-") {
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        }}
        onPaste={e => {
          const reg = "^[-]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*$";
          const current = e.target.value;
          if (!current) {
            e.target.value = "";
          }
          if (
            !(current + e.clipboardData.getData("Text")).match(reg) &&
            e.clipboardData.getData("Text").match(reg)
          ) {
            e.target.value = "";
          }
          if (!e.clipboardData.getData("Text").match(reg)) {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        }}
      />
```

The key press events allow for single minuses and avoid double minuses

Furthermore onPaste method will allow only valid numbers to be pasted

If the to be pasted clipboard is not a number then it will not be pasted.

If the current value + the clipboard is not a number only the clipboard will be pasted otherwise the current value + the to be pasted clipboard will be pasted.

Comment: This works well. The only thing I changed was the regex in `onPaste`. Using `*` allows for `-.`. I changed it to `const reg = "^[-]?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]+$";`.

Comment: Very helpful. Now that `onKeyPress` is deprecated in React, I was able to implement a solution using `onKeyUp` (plus `onPaste`) instead. But `e.preventDefault()` is unfortunately too late in the case of `onKeyUp` so I had to use a ref to keep track of the previous value and set input.value to that instead (the ref for the previous value gets updated in both onKeyUp and onPaste).