# Restrict double minus in mui number textfiled

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui, textfield

Currently, Number type inputs accepting double minus (i.e: `--1`). But I want only one `-` sign. If user press another minus then it should preventDefault().

Found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73073818/14588135) here. But it has some edge cases like, if user input '-123' and then go back and remove the '-' then user can't give the '-' again.

Answer (score 1):

Since such values (-786-6, --712, ...) are allowed in `TextField` of `type="number"`

What I did is changing the `textField` proprety `type` from `number` to `text`, yes we'll accept strings but the user will be forced to enter a valid number.

Let's create a `useState` hook for the `TextField` input :

```
const [entredValue,setEntredValue] = useState('');
```

Then each time we verify if the entred `input` is a valid number before updating `entredValue`. this is a `function` made for that :

```
function restrict(test) {
  if (test.length === 1) {
    if (test[0] !== "-" && isNaN(test[0]) && test[0] !== ".") return false;
  } else if (test.length === 2) {
    if (isNaN(test) && test !== "-.") return false;
  } else {
    if (isNaN(test)) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Then update the state value this way :

```
<TextField
 onChange={(event) => {
 if (restrict(event.target.value)) {
 setEntredValue(event.target.value);
 }}}
/>
```

Comment: This isn't work for `type='number'` .If I give `--something` , it returns `'' (empty string)` in `e.target.value`. I need the arrows of number field.

Comment: should be type='text'